# Finding next x months of data

Tags: excel, vba, date

I want to find the first 36 months of spend for each customer (name). The data I have only goes back into 2015, so customers like Bob, the "100" value should be his 3rd month spend, because he started 3 months prior in 2014. Meanwhile, Kimmi's first month is Feb 2015 and in Troy's case he only made it 34 months and there is only one value for him.

This is how the data looks:

```
  Name      Start       End      1/31/2015   2/29/2015   3/31/2015   4/30/2015  
 ------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
  Bob     11/5/2014    N/A             100        150        200        250  
  Kimmi   2/4/2015    N/A               0        500        960       1000  
  Troy    2/9/2012    1/1/2015         50          0          0          0
```

I am attempting to make a table like:

```
  Name    Month 1   Month 2   ...   Month 6   ...   Month 34   Month 35   Month 36  
 ------- --------- --------- ----- --------- ----- ---------- ---------- ---------- 
  Bob     N/A       N/A             100                  ...   ...        ...       
  Kimmi   500       960             ...                  ...   ...        ...       
  Troy    N/A       N/A             N/A                   50   N/A        N/A
```

I have tried using:

```
=IF(B2<"1/1/2015",INDEX(OldTable!$D$2:$G$4,MATCH(NewTable!A2,OldTable!$A$2:$A$4,0),MATCH(1,(MONTH(B2)=MONTH($C$1:$F$1))*(YEAR(B2)=YEAR($C$1:$F$1),0)),FALSE)
```

The problem is that I can't match the start date in the new table to the column header dates in the old table.

```
MATCH(1,(MONTH(B2)=MONTH($C$1:$F$1))*(YEAR(B2)=YEAR($C$1:$F$1)),0)
```

This piece of code specifically is the where the error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is this something you doing through worksheet functions? Is this something you are trying through VBA? Please edit your question to include your own attempt, and edit the tags to include your method.

Comment: *how can I find the first 36 months after their start date?* `=EDATE(startdate,36)` will return a date 36 months greater than *startdate*

Comment: @JvdV I edited to show some code

Comment: How would I return the data in between start date and the date returned by the EDATE function?